# Counting, Adding and Dividing using MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table tblscore with scores in which I would Count all those with same name and level, Add there scores divided by total count.

```
 ID | Name | Level | Score
 1  | John | Easy  | 15
 2  | Doe  | Easy  | 18
 3  | John | Easy  | 13
```

Display output will be

```
 Name | Level | Score
 John | Easy  | 14
 Doe  | Easy  | 18
```

computation is John with 2 entries having same level (15+13 / 2 = 14) wherein 2 is the total count of the data with same name and level.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `avg()`:

```
select name, level, avg(score)
from tblscore
group by name, level
```

Comment: wasn't expecting this was too easy.